# Using LIKE operator in MySQL with comma s issue

Tags: mysql, sql-like

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  store_id as `initial`,
  CONCAT(',', store_id, ',') AS store_id
FROM `mytable` AS `main_table`
WHERE (`store_id` LIKE '%,13,%');
```

These are the results without the `where` conditions:

[image]

When I executed my query , I got no results. Same for `WHERE (`store_id`LIKE '%,3,%');` Is it some kind of rule or exception for the `,` and `like` operator  ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad DB design. Think about normalization

Comment: @Jens , I know, but I wasn't the one who did this :) I was the one who received it like this

Comment: Read about `find_in_set`. It will help you in the meantime

Comment: @Jens Beside thinking of normalization or refactoring the all project is there a solution for this ? or smth that I can do ? Thank you

Comment: Any reason for `FROM \`mytable\` AS \`main_table\``? Without it seems [working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6386b/2) - Removed `AS ...` (update: actually it [works with it too?!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6386b/5))

Answer (score 2):

Using FIND_IN_SET fixed my problem.  More Info:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php .

Credit goes to @Jens

```
SELECT
  store_id as `store_id`,
FROM `ffm_nonpayment_actiontemplate` AS `main_table`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('13', store_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that field `store_id` in WHERE has initial value and not the value you calculate with `CONCAT(',', store_id, ',') AS store_id`
If you want filter you can use `HAVING` keyword